# RAML 1.0 include multiple files with resources

Tags: raml

I want to define REST resources in multiple files and include them in a single RAML file 
I tried [this](http://forums.raml.org/t/include-external-resources-raml-file-in-one-uber-file/212/4) but i always get RAML errors

Main.raml
    `#%RAML 1.0
title: Main RAML file to include All APIs
version: v1
baseUri: http://api.samplehost.com
/student: !include student.raml`

student.raml

`#%RAML 1.0
    title: student APIs
    version: v1
    baseUri: http://api.samplehost.com
    /student:
      get:  # ..etc`

but I get Unknown Error in the included file: Unknown node: 'title' in Main.raml

when I remove the 'title' from the included file 'student.raml'
I got Unknown Missing required property 'title' in the student.raml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it´s not possible to do this with RAML.

For me the Best way to accomplished this problem is to use the RAML Library and use resource types, traits and types to be associated with routes that you want to exposed.

For more information see [RAML 1.0 documentation](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md).

Comment: can you please give me an example of how to associate types to routes?

Answer (score 1):

According to [raml-org issue](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/issues/515), your **student.raml** file should have something like this:

> get:

the important part here is removing the first line

```
#%RAML 1.0
```